# How can I edit a file in app bundle?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app, I load data from a CSV file stored in the bundle resources. However, I'd like to be able to update this file programmatically when the user taps the Update button. Is there a way to change a resource in the app bundle programatically? Here is the code I use to access the file:

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"query_result" ofType:@"csv"];
    NSArray *rows = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile:path];
```

Comment: `Documents` folder is your playground here, you cannot edit / update / modify anything in the bundle as long as you'd like to keep your application AppStore-safe.

Comment: I see. So I should be putting it in the Documents directory?

Answer (score 1):

First of all load file from bundle and after that just store in Document directory then you can make change on this file again save on document directory to access changed file.

Use this code copy from mainbundle to Document.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;

NSString *dataPath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tessdata"];
NSLog(@"Datapath is %@", dataPath);

// If the expected store doesn't exist, copy the default store.    
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dataPath] == NO)
    {
        NSString *tessdataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"eng" ofType:@"traineddata"];
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:tessdataPath toPath:dataPath error:&error];

    }

-(NSString*) applicationDocumentsDirectory{
    // Get the documents directory
    NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    return docsDir;
}
```

And then get the Saved file to change...

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask,
                                                     YES);

NSString *fullPath = [[paths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"recentDownload.txt"];
```

Comment: Is the documents directory maintained when the app is closed?

Comment: Yes It is maintained until and unless you are not going to delete the application.