# Edit a JSON file in Swift 5 | Xcode 11

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, save

oke, I'm trying to load from a JSON file (which I've done) but I can't figure out how to edit the file. I'm trying to change a boolean from false to true. I've tried quite a few methods and none are working with the setup I have got.
Here is a version of my code:
file1 (SpotsData.swift):

```
import Foundation
struct SpotsData: Codable{

    var spot_id: Int
    var spot_name: String
    var spot_long: Double
    var spot_lat: Double
    var spot_complete : Bool


}
```

file4 (ViewController.swift) there is more code but this is what is relevant

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {

        let data = DataLoader().spotsData //loads the data
        print(data) //shows the data
        print(data[1].spots_complete)//the thing I want to change(prints false)

   }
```

file5(DataLoader.swift) // this is what loads my data

```
import Foundation
public class DataLoader{

  @Published var spotsData = [SpotsData]()
    init(){
        load()
        sort()
    }
    func load(){
        if let fileLocation = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "spots", withExtension: "JSON"){
            do{
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileLocation)
                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                let dataFromJson = try jsonDecoder.decode([SpotsData].self, from: data)
                self.spotsData = dataFromJson
            }
            catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    func sort(){
        self.spotsData = self.spotsData.sorted(by:{$0.spot_id < $1.spot_id})
    }
}
```

file6 (spots.JSON) //my data [the long and lat have data but are 0 for this]

```
[
    {
        "spot_id" : 0,
        "spot_name" : "windmill",
        "spot_lat" : 00000,
        "spot_long" : 00000,
        "spot_complete" : false
    },

    {
        "spot_id" : 1,
        "spot_name" : "rock",
        "spot_lat" : 0000,
        "spot_long" : -0000,
        "spot_complete" : false
    },

    {
        "spot_id" : 2,
        "spot_name" : "patio",
        "spot_lat" : 000,
        "spot_long" : -000,
        "spot_complete" : false
    },

    {
        "spot_id" : 3,
        "spot_name" : "dogging",
        "spot_lat" : 000,
        "spot_long" : -0000,
        "spot_complete" : false
    }

]
```

Ye i also have appDelegate and sceneDelegate but they have not been changed for this project. I was trying to find a way to update them just as a reverse so I could do save[1].spots_complete = true. Then it would have the file by having the other functions in other sections or files as i have previously. Any help would be great thanks I have been stuck on this for a while now. 
Many Thanks :)

Comment: why not having a model with variables and functions which manipulates and supplies  'SpotsData' ?

Comment: im unsure what you mean, its the spots.json I want to edit. jus to change the spots complete to true @good4pc

Comment: You cannot edit files saved in bundle. Refer this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24914769/how-can-i-edit-a-file-in-app-bundle

Comment: @good4pc - how would i save it to the documents instead